# VBA filter values in Pivot table from values stored in dynamic range

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I am trying to select only values in PivotTable1 from values stored in range "str" excluding any blank in filter, by running below code I am not getting values in filter. whart is the problem with this code and is there any alternate solution for my requirement.

```
Dim star As String
Dim startRange As String
Dim lastRange As String

startRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Peer Code").Range("J2").Address

lastRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Peer Code").Range("J" & LR0).Address

 star = startRange & ":" & lastRange

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Conso_Input").Activate
 Dim PI As PivotItem
  
 With 
 Worksheets("Conso_Input").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("FundCode")
    .ClearAllFilters
    For Each PI In .PivotItems
        PI.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(star), PI.Name) > 0
    Next PI
 End With
```

#### New code

```
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Peer Code").Activate
    Dim LR0 As Integer
   LR0 = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim star As String
Dim startRange As String
Dim lastRange As String

startRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Peer Code").Range("J2").Address

lastRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Peer Code").Range("J" & LR0).Address

 star = startRange & ":" & lastRange

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Conso_Input").Activate

    Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
    Dim PvtFld As PivotField
    Dim PI As PivotItem
    Dim MatchFound As Boolean, i As Long
    
    ' set the Pivot Table
    Set PvtTbl = 
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Conso_Input").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    
    ' set the Pivot Field
    Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("FundCode")
    
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Conso_Input").Activate
   
   PvtTbl.ClearAllFilters
   
   For Each PI In PvtFld.PivotItems
   'For Each PI In .PvtTbl.PivotItems
   
        PI.Visible = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(star), PI.Name) > 0
   Next PI
```

Comment: `Range(str)` may want to qualify that with an explicit worksheet object

Comment: @TimWilliams, Thanks Tim.  I have added the code for str variable, Can you suggest any improvement here.

Comment: `Range(str)` should be explicitly attached to a specific worksheet, otherwise it will default to the ActiveSheet (which is not always what you expect, depending on what else is going on in your code)  Likewise for `Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @TimWilliams with active sheet range code is running well, I have created range variable to get values from another sheet but the code is sourcing only one value. what is the problem in this code

Comment: I don't see that you've really made any changes ?

Comment: @TimWilliams can this filtering is possible without using with sheets as I want to select values from another sheet

Comment: @TimWilliams I have created new code in order to isolate worksheet fuction but still range star variable values  are getting selected in pivot item, can you please help

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks Tim for the code . I tried running it however its still not sourcing the values  from rngstar and only one value is getting selected in filter with error  "unable to visible property of pivot item class"

Comment: That likely means there are no matches in rngStar - you can't hide the last pivot field item and that's why you get the error.  Sorry there's not much else I can suggest unless you can share the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim wsPC As Worksheet, wsCI As Worksheet
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable, rngStar As Range
Dim PvtFld As PivotField, PI As PivotItem, m

Set wsCI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Conso_Input")
Set wsPC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Peer Code")

Set rngStar = wsPC.Range("J2:J" & wsPC.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)

Set PvtTbl = wsCI.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
PvtTbl.ClearAllFilters
Set PvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("FundCode")
For Each PI In PvtFld.PivotItems
    m = Application.Match(PI.Name, rngStar, 0)
    PI.Visible = Not IsError(m)
Next PI
```